# Views for a question

Tags: support, questions

If a person opens a particular question more than once, are the *views incremented just once or multiple times?*

Comment: Pretty sure that this has been asked before, but it's something like of the same user waits 15 minutes between viewing the page, then the counter is increased, otherwise not.

Comment: ... and indeed, here it is: [How are the number of views in a question calculated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728/)